# Lumen 5.1 seeding with output from tests

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, testing, phpunit, lumen

To be able to run the integration tests with database testing I wrote a seeder, that seeds Messages table with fake messages for a fake, newly created user. This user's ID is then required to retrieve the messages, so inside the seeder class I simply **print** its ID.

Then in a test I call the following:

```
$output = new BufferedOutput;
$exitCode = \Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => UserMessagesSeeder'], $output);
```

This should let me retrieve the output with the following:

```
$output->fetch()
```

However the above always returns null.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or perhaps there is a better way to call a seeder? Should I simply include the entire factory to my testing class and call it when necessary? It seems cumbersome, to be fair.

Comment: Wait you are doing an Artisan call from inside another seeder?

Comment: no, this is from inside a phpunit test, in a class that extends TestCase

Answer (score 0):

So obviously there is a simple workaround, rather than run artisan seeding command, the Seeder class can be used inside the test as follows:

```
$seeder = new UserMessagesSeeder;
$user_id = $seeder->run();
```

The above combined with DatabaseTransactions trait can be a very useful tool to run your integration tests and as you can see any value from inside the seeder can be returned by **run** method.